# Regex to filter BBCode lists

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to improve legacy PHP code that deals with cleaning-up BBCode from a string and am currently facing trouble with lists.

The current solution for lists does the following:

```php
...
$search[]  = sprintf('~\[%s\](.*)\[/%s\]~smUi', 'list', 'list');
$search[]  = sprintf('~\[%s=(.*)\](.*)\[/%s\]~smUi', 'list', 'list');
$search[]  = sprintf('~\[\%s\]~i', '*');
$replace[] = '$1';
$replace[] = '$2';
$replace[] = '';
...
return preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

This works fine when the string is something like

```
[list]
  [*]Item 1
  [*]Item 2
  [*]Item 3
[/list]
```

But it will also strip `[*]` if it's not inside lists and also fails with things like:

```
[list]
  [*][list]
    [*]Item 1.1
    [*]Item 1.2
    [*]Item 1.3
  [/list]
  [*]Item 2
  [*]Item 3
[/list]
```

Is it even possible using RegExp only to strip the `[list]` or `[list=1]` + `[/list]` tags along with `[*]` if they are within lists?

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
$search[]  = sprintf('~\[(%s)(?:=[^]]*)?]((?:(?!\[\1\b).)*?)\[/\1]\s*~si', 'list');
$search[]  = sprintf('~\[%s]~i', '\\*');
$replace[] = '$2';
$replace[] = '';
$count = 0;
do {
  $string = preg_replace($search, $replace, $string, -1, $count);
}
while ($count > 0);
return $string;
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/9f225).

I merged the first two regexps since they basically match the same (the `=.*?` part inside the open tag is just optional, I suggest using `(?:=[^]]*)?` to match `=` and then 0+ chars other than `]` 1 or 0 times.

The `((?:(?!\[\1\b).)*?)` pattern is a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794) that ensures that the innermost `list` tag is matched, `\1` here matches the tag name that is captured with `(%s)`.

The `$count` variable will hold the number of replacements done with `preg_replace`, and if nothing is replaced, the `while` block exits.